# Function to determine a matrix is in row echelon form or not gives wrong output

Tags: python, linear-algebra

I need to write a function to determine a matrix is in row echelon form or not. I wrote the code below but it gives wrong output when all-zero rows is between a non-zero row and all-zero row. How can I fix it?

```
import numpy as np

def is_row_echelon_form(matrix):
    # Get the dimensions of the matrix.
    num_rows, num_cols = len(matrix), len(matrix[0])

    # Track a key variable to find the first non-zero element in each row.
    key_variable = -1

    for row in range(num_rows):
        if row == num_cols:
            break
        # Find the first non-zero element in each row.
        while key_variable < num_cols - 1:
            key_variable += 1
            if matrix[row][key_variable] != 0:
                break

        if matrix[row][key_variable] != 0:
            # Check if all elements above and below the key variable are zero.
            for i in range(row + 1, num_rows):
                if matrix[i][key_variable] != 0:
                    return False
        else:
            if any(matrix[row][key_variable:]):
                return False

    return True
```

Comment: matrix = [
    [1, 2, 0, 3],
    [0, 1, 0, 2],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
]
here is example input. it should return false but returns true

Comment: Any additional information should be added directly to the question with an [edit].

Comment: The logic of your code looks messy. Just find the index of the first non-zero of the line, and check that it is greater than the one of the line before.

Comment: You already loading numpy. Just check whether the leading pivot for each row is greater than the leading entry of every non-zero row above it. something like `all(np.diff(np.argmax(matrix!=0, 1))>1)`. Of course you will need a few more tests before this. ie do you want rows with all elements 0? ie if you want the rank to be equal to the columns of the matrix, then you check first for any row containing all zeros. If you have a rectangular matrix, you index accordingly